# Error code: 502-backend/ 502 Bad Gateway in Flask Application

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, pythonanywhere

I hosted my web app on [www.pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com).

I took all the measures like placing app.run() in `if __name__ == "__main__"` and checked the error logs, modifying wsgi.py file and looked, tried other answers.

I couldn't resolve the issue at all.

ERRORS in error.log is as follows

```
2022-04-17 13:54:19   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 950, in handle
2022-04-17 13:54:19     self.emit(record)
2022-04-17 13:54:19   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1084, in emit
2022-04-17 13:54:19     stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
2022-04-17 13:54:19   File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 170, in write
2022-04-17 13:54:19     self.logger.error(line)
2022-04-17 13:54:19   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1463, in error
2022-04-17 13:54:19     self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
2022-04-17 13:54:19   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1577, in _log
2022-04-17 13:54:19     self.handle(record)
2022-04-17 13:54:19   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1587, in handle
2022-04-17 13:54:19     self.callHandlers(record)
2022-04-17 13:54:19   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1649, in callHandlers
2022-04-17 13:54:19     hdlr.handle(record)
2022-04-17 13:54:19   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 950, in handle
2022-04-17 13:54:19     self.emit(record)
2022-04-17 13:54:19   File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 113, in emit
2022-04-17 13:54:19     format_with_millis(datetime.now()), self.format(record)
2022-04-17 13:54:19   File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 99, in format_with_millis
2022-04-17 13:54:19     return "{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S},{:03d}".format(
2022-04-17 13:54:19 RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I think problem is on server side wsgi configurations..

Comment: This error log does not give complete picture, Include your wsgi.py and flask_app.py here, maybe you are making a recursive call in one of your functions

Comment: Are you writing a very long line to the logger or to print something very long?  That can sometimes cause the logging system to trigger an error, which it will then try to log, which triggers another error, and so on, which can cause infinite recursion.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.